# How to pass data to all views in Laravel 5.6?

Tags: laravel

I have two controllers. StudentController and TeacherController. I have a variable `$chat` which I want to pass in all the views of StudentController and TeacherController. The `$chat` will contain different data for both these controllers.

I searched and found ways, but I am getting empty data. I am doing it like this.

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use View;
class StudentController extends Controller {



public function __construct()
{

    $this->middleware('auth')->except(['home']);

    $this->middleware('access')->except(['home']);

    $chats = studentChat();

    View::share('chats', $chats);

}
```

So, here I am printing and it is returning an empty array, but when I use the same in a function the array contains data. What is wrong here? Can anyone please help?

What I tried:

```
  public function boot()
{

  View::composer('*', function ($view) {

  $chats = Cache::remember('chats', 60, function () {

  if(Auth::user()->user_type() == config('constant.student'))
  {
    return studentChat();

  }
  else
  {
    return teacherChat();

  }

  });

 $view->with('chats', $chats);
});

}
```

Comment: I believe View::share only works when used in a service provider. I would just set a property of $this->chats with your data in the constructor and then manually pass it down to all the views within the controller using with()

Comment: Well, I know that way, but want to know about any simpler way.

Comment: @Rob put `studentChat()` code in question

Comment: @J.Doe Added now.

Comment: @Rob I think your query return null, try `DB::enableQueryLog(); studentChat(); dd(DB::getQueryLog());` - this is your raw sql query, analyze it

Comment: Well, when I run it any of the function like `public function abc() { $chats = studentChat()}` and if I `dd($chat)` here it gives an array with the values. When I write it in the `public __construct() { $chat = studentChat();}`. It gives an empty array. I have nevere used `DB::enableQueryLog();`. Can you please guide me where to write it?

Comment: Okay so I did and I got the query and the interesting fact is that the where details are coming empty in this dd. I do not know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, what I did was in the AppServiceProvider class, in the boot function I added this.

```
      View::composer('*', function ($view) {


  if(!\Auth::check())
  {

      return;

  }

  $userType = \Auth::user()->user_type ;



  if($userType == config('constant.student'))
  {
    $chats = studentChat();

  }
  else if($userType == config('constant.teacher'))
  {
    $chats = teacherChat();

  }


 $view->with('chats', $chats);

 });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `View::share` your share data to ALL your view, if you need to add data to few different views you may do this:

Create blade file(chat.blade.php for your case), and put your variables:

```
<? $chats = studentChat(); ?>
```

Include this file to the begining of your views where your need this 'global' varables:

```
//begin of your blade file
@include('chat')
//some code

{{ $chat->channel }}
```

Comment: Okay, I understood your point, but what is this `{{ $chat->channel }}` and where should I use it?

Comment: @Rob i updated answer, `{{ $chat->channel }}` this your variable what you share to staudent/teach views

Answer (score 1):

**Sharing Data With All Views**

Occasionally, you may need to share a piece of data with all views that are rendered by your application. You may do so using the view facade's share method. Typically, you should place calls to share within a service provider's boot method. You are free to add them to the  AppServiceProvider or generate a separate service provider to house them:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    public function boot()
    {
         $chats = studentChat();

         View::share('chats', $chats);
    }


    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
```

}

Comment: See it works, but the `$chat` is coming empty here, though it is not empty in real. Why is it throwing an empty array?

Comment: Did you tried to debug/dump what is in $chats? please check dd($chats);

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data to the view Like.

```
return View::make('demo')->with('posts', $posts);
```

For more details visit article : [Introduction to Routing in Laravel](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/routing-in-laravel/)

Comment: I know about that way. I want to pass this variable to all the views at once and not one by one.

Answer (score 0):

write your query in boot method in appServiceProvider like,

```
View::composer('*', function ($view) {
    $share_query = Cache::remember('share_query', 60,function () {
        return App\User::all();
    });
     $view->with('share_query', $share_query);
});
```

Comment: Okay, so this works. But, now I have two Controllers. The chat for teacher and student are different. How can I pass them in both of them??  What I have tried is updated above in the question. It is not working. Any idea?

Comment: you can used `View::composer('*', function ($view) {
    $chat_teacher = Cache::remember('chat_teacher', 60,function () {
        return App\User::chat()->get();
    });
     $view->with('chat_teacher', $chat_teacher);
});` and in view you can fetch teacher chat like `$chat_teacher->chat` same for students

Answer (score 0):

Your final solution is ok, but not the cleanest possible.
Here is what i would do.

Define a class with a single function that contains your logic and return $chats, that way you will encapsulate your logic properly and keep your service provider boot method clean.

Then you have 2 options:

- Inject your class in the boot() method of the service provider you use, then call its function and uses View::share. Should looks like :

```
public function boot(ChatResolver $chatResolver)
{
    $chats = $chatResolver->getChats();
    View::share(compact('chats));
}
```

If you only use $chats variable in a signe view or partial (like a part of layout), you can also inject the class you defined directly in the view. 
Here is a link to [Laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade#service-injection) regarding that.
In some cases it might be the easiest solution.